# Counting binary words by runs

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I would like to count the number of binary words that have $m$ zeros, $n$ ones and $k$ runs of ones (consecutive blocks of ones). Call it $a(m,n,k)$. I tried to apply the symbolic method and introduced the class $\cal{A} = \{\text{ binary words } \}$ and the generating function

$$A(x,y,z) = \sum_{\alpha \in\cal{A}} x^{|\alpha|_0}y^{|\alpha|_1}z^{|\alpha|_r}$$

where $|\alpha|_k$ is the number of digits $k=0,1$ in $\alpha$ and $|\alpha|_r$ is the number of runs of ones.

Now I think the following holds (since a word either has some amount of ones as the first run (with some amount of zeros in front), or it has no ones)

$$\cal{A} = \left( \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \{ \underbrace{0\dots0}_j  \underbrace{1\dots 1}_m0 \} \times \cal{A} \right ) \bigcup \{\varepsilon, 0, 00, 000, \dots\}$$

And from this we get an equation for the generating function:

$$A
= \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{j+1}y^mzA\right) + 1+x+x^2+\dots
\\= \frac{x}{1-x} \frac{y}{1-y}z A + \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
And hence
$$
\\A= \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1- \frac{xy}{(1-x)(1-y)}z}
\\= \frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{xy}{(1-x)(1-y)}\right)^kz^k
\\= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^ky^k (1-x)^{-k-1} (1-y)^{-k} z^k
\\= \sum_{m\geq 0} \sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{k\geq 0} (-1)^{m+n}{{-k-1}\choose{m}}{{-k}\choose{n}} x^{m+k}y^{n+k}z^k
\\= \sum_{m\geq k} \sum_{n\geq k} \sum_{k\geq 0} (-1)^{m+n}{{-k-1}\choose{m-k}}{{-k}\choose{n-k}} x^{m}y^{n}z^k
$$

From here we see the solution

$$a(m,n,k) = (-1)^{m+n}{{-k-1}\choose{m-k}}{{-k}\choose{n-k}}
\\= {{m}\choose{k}}{{n}\choose{k-1}}
$$

But I think this is incorrect, since for example for $m=0$ you should always have $1$ run, but in my result the first factor will make it $0$. Where is my error? My source for the problem is [this homework question 2](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/EC/Homework/hw2.pdf) and there are also solutions [on the page](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/EC/homework.html), but I would like to solve it myself.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to fix this, but the problem is that your decomposition of $\mathcal A$ does not account for strings whose last character is $1$. Indeed, the only place $1$s appear is in $\{00\dots011\dots10\}$, and there they are followed by a $0$.

Comment: Also, the $\binom{-k}{n-k}$ should become $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you are not counting strings which end with a $1$. That is, letting $\mathcal B=\{\text{binary words ending in 0}\}\cup\{\epsilon\}$, and letting $B(x,y,z)=\sum_{\beta\in \mathcal B}x^{|\beta|_0}y^{|\beta|_1}z^{|\beta|_r}$, you have shown that 
$$
B(x,y,z)= \sum_{m\geq k} \sum_{n\geq k} \sum_{k\geq 0} {{m}\choose{k}}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}} x^{m}y^{n}z^k
$$
However, there is a quick fix. You can note that
$$
xA(x,y,z)+1=B(x,y,z)
$$
corresponding the to the equation $\mathcal B=(\mathcal A\times \{0\})\cup \{\epsilon\}$. This gives you

$$
A(x,y,z)= \sum_{m\geq k} \sum_{n\geq k} \sum_{k\geq 0} {{m}\choose{k}}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}} x^{m-1}y^{n}z^k
$$
Extracting the $[x^my^nz^k]$ coefficient, you get $\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

---

Here is a different method which works; let

$\mathcal M=\{\text{binary words beginning with a }0\}\cup \{\epsilon\}$,
$\mathcal N=\{\text{binary words beginning with a }1\}$.

Then you get the mutual recurrence
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal M &= \left(\bigcup_{i\ge1}0^i× \mathcal N\right)\cup \{\epsilon,0,00,\dots\},\\
\mathcal N &= \left(\bigcup_{i\ge1}1^i× \mathcal M\right)
\end{align}
$$
which, letting $M$ and $N$ be the corresponding generating functions, implies
$$
\begin{align}
M&=\frac{x}{1-x}N + \frac1{1-x}\\
N&=\frac{yz}{1-y}M
\end{align}
$$
You can then solve this system for $M$ and $N$. Conclude by noting $A=M+N$.